# Safe lubricants to use is not primarily opinion based

Tags: support, reopen-request

Please consider reopening [What lubricants can be safely added to a laptop fan?](https://superuser.com/questions/1007968/what-lubricants-can-be-safely-added-to-a-laptop-fan)

It was closed as "primarily opinion based", but the question is not an opinion-based question: "Are there any lubricants that are safe to use inside a laptop?"

The large number of upvotes also clearly indicates that this question is valued by our community.

Comment: I **reluctantly** just added the discrimination tag, because after reading a specific moderator's choice to claim I wrote things that I obviously did not write, I must question if there is some discrimination or bias at play.

Comment: Discrimination? We really shouldn't have meta tags on meta.

Comment: You are taking your question being closed way to personally.  There isn't any discrimination happening.  Most audit reviewers don't even pay attention to who is submitting a question, I know personally, I don't even read who submitted a question or an answer before I make a decision my recommendation on what should happen (close, delete, nothing).

Comment: @Ramhound I certainly did not consider any discrimination until I witnessed how certain people were acting and were refusing to apologize for their actions.  I'm not going to name names because those people know who they are and this is not worth my time.

Answer (score 5):

IMO, it's a duplicate:

- [What can be used to lubricate a rattling fan?](https://superuser.com/questions/707574/what-can-be-used-to-lubricate-a-rattling-fan)
- [Can I use oil from the kitchen for oiling my fans?](https://superuser.com/questions/366573/can-i-use-oil-from-kitchen-for-oiling-my-fans)
- [What is better oil for oiling fans: grapeseed or refined?](https://superuser.com/questions/370244/what-is-better-oil-for-oiling-fans-grapeseed-or-refined?lq=1)
- [How to oil SMPS fan?](https://superuser.com/questions/263130/how-to-oil-smps-fan?rq=1)

Comment: Thanks!  It's interesting that not a single one of those questions was closed for being off-topic or opinion based.

Comment: @RockPaperLizard Keep in mind that the rules or what's acceptable (and what's not) changes over time on SU, and sometime things that should be closed slip by.  So (regardless of the question at hand here) don't assume that just because a similar question exists means that another one like it is (still) OK. ;)

Comment: "It's interesting that not a single one of those questions was closed for being off-topic or opinion based" - Now that you have brought these questions to our attention, that might change, as Techie hints the type of questions deemed acceptable continuously is changing..

Comment: I am not a moderator so I can't moderate anything.

Comment: There is at least on that was closed as duplicate. But they should all be closed as off topic. Thanks for pointing them out.

Answer (score 1):

Agree. This should be re-opened.

And then closed properly as a product/shopping recommendation question as it's asking for suggestions on what type of product to use here.

Answer (score 1):

I'm Andy, from Hardware Recommendations.

As the question stands, it should **not** be migrated to Hardware Recommendations.

The question, as I understand it, is:

> Are there any lubricants that are safe to use inside a laptop?

There is also an implied:

> What lubricant should I get?

This is not on topic. Lubricant is not hardware. Our Meta post on [What is Hardware?](https://hardwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/265/what-is-hardware) has this to say:

> Hardware is any **primarily electronic item** that can perform more than one task, designed to interface with, connect to, or be, a **primary computing platform** in day-to-day operation.
>
> A **primary computing platform** is any primarily electronic item that can **perform meaningful tasks** on its own with minimal external support, and designed to be **operated by a user**, consumer or professional.

Lubricant doesn't fit this.

---

If you are going to change it to a question about what replacement fan to get, then you need to add more details about the laptop. Make, model, size of fan. A broad question such as "What fan should I get?" will be closed. If you've narrowed it down to a small list of fans you are considering, we can help. If you have unique requirements for your fan (ie. it spins and sings a jingle, but only on Tuesdays after a full moon), we can help. But, simply asking for a fan that fits your laptop will not work.

Finally, your question *sounds* like a technical support question, so I urge you to rework it, because we don't allow those either.

Answer (score 0):

It is most closely a duplicate of [What can be used to lubricate a rattling fan?](https://superuser.com/questions/707574/what-can-be-used-to-lubricate-a-rattling-fan) (Many thanks to Techie007 for finding that question.)

However, it has received much more attention than that question, and many more useful answers.

Perhaps the best solution would be to keep it, and add a pointer in all related questions so our community can easily find the best (and most current) answers.

I'm not sure moderator random is acting in the best interest of StackExchange.

His/her quick response to my request for re-opening is snarky and quite unhelpful compared to how SE moderators are encouraged to behave.

Apparently, he/she closed my question, which has received many upvotes, for the wrong reason. Instead of apologizing and acknowledging his/her error, his/her suggestion is to re-open it and close it again for a different reason.

Although my question will surely get the best responses on this SE, every SE has "off topic" and "on topic" guidelines. As such, I have no problem if the consensus is that this question is off-topic on this SE.

But I'm not okay with random's statement that he/she should just re-open it and then immediately re-close it. Especially not for such a popular question.

Update: It's unfortunate that in response, "random" then publicly made statements that I made requests that I did not, and then another moderator took actions to remove all that evidence from public view.

Comment: HR moderator here. This question as it stands wouldn't be on-topic at HR, given that it's not requesting an electronic device (it's requesting lubricant). See http://meta.hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/266/1 for more information on our scope in its current form.

Comment: There you go. This isn't on topic there at all.